# Stop/delete a container once merge request gets approved

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab pipeline which is executing and creating a docker container. Now whenever some merge request raise (i.e. from feature branch to develop branch) my feature branch will get delete.
So, I want to stop/delete the containers related to feature branch. Can anyone please help me how I can implement this using gitlab?

Comment: That highly depends on how your container is created/started in the first place. Is it on a DinD service on CI? On a distant server?

Comment: I am able to fix it. Below is the yml file which worked for me:
.only-default: &only-default
  only:
    - merge_requests
    
Cleanup:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - docker stop your_container_name
  only:
    - merge_requests

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix it after few trail and errors. Below code worked for me.

.only-default: &only-default
only:
- merge_requests

Cleanup:
stage: cleanup
script:
- docker stop your_container_id_name
only:
- merge_requests